# Poisson Manifold Structures on Even Dimensional Spheres

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces, poisson-geometry

The $2n$-sphere, for $n=1,2,3$, possess  a (non-trivial) Poisson manifold structure. Is this still true for $n > 3$? Describing the spheres as homogeneous spaces $SO(n)/S(n-1)$, are there Poisson structures (should they exist) equivariant?

Comment: This question overlaps with this one http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150571/does-the-4-sphere-have-a-nonzero-poisson-structure-as-a-poisson-homogeneous-spac?rq=1 where you can find some answers for your question (depending on what you mean by "equivariant")

Comment: Are you concerned about Poisson structures on even spheres or on all spheres, because your question contradicts the title?
Non trivial in itself doesn't say much. You can have a nontrivial Poisson structure on any manifold (of dim. >1).

Comment: Just even. Sorry, the n-sphere should have been 2n. It's fixed now.